# How HttpContext works in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, httprequest, httpcontext

I am trying to understand the detail of how httpcontext works in .NET ?

What I couldnt understand is the class of HttpContext has a field of static HttpContext object. So for each request from client creates an instance of an httpcontext or not ? Why it defined as static ? Does it mean one application can only has one httpcontext ?

I am confused so the way that ask the question can be little bit complex. I hope it is understandable.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you access the static member, it resolves the *current* request ***relative to the thread***.

No, this does not mean there is only one, in the same way that Thread.Current doesnt mean there is only one thread. Each request has a different HttpContext.

As a trivial way to do something similar (I don't know if it is implemented this way, though);

```
[ThreadStatic]
public static string TryMeFromDifferentThreads;
```

Comment: how .net decides to create a httpcontext in another thread? For example if the application has a httpcontext that is not null at that time, if another request come up then it creates another httpcontext on another thread ? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Kaplan essentially yes, but more complex - a single request can actually jump between threads at some specific points (mainly relating to async request/response context access)

Comment: I want to understand the detail of it, is there any reference that you can advice me to read? thanks for your nice explanations.

Comment: @kaplan I think most of it is "implementation detail" meaning: subject to change.  The behaviour, though; is simple: current gives you the one you need to worry about. You could run reflector on .Current, of coursr